# Ideas for how to triage a bluetooth headset/laptop that makes a reconnection noise whenever I search in either google/edge

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth, microsoft-edge, notifications

I have my phone and laptop connected to a bluetooth headset. Whenver I search on Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge the sound cuts out from my phone, the headset makes a connection noise, and then stays silent for 1-5 seconds before bringing back the cellphone audio while also still playing whatever comes from the laptop. I use a VoIP app on my phone for work, and this will cut out the call I'm on.

Dell Latitude E5550

Plantronics Voyager Legend

OS Windows 10 Pro, Version 21H2, Build 19044.1889
Microsoft Edge Version 105.0.1343.33 (64-bit)
Chrome Version 105.0.5195.102 (64-bit)

I have tried silencing notifications on both browsers, general notifications in Windows, as well as various settings in Dell Audio, all to no avail. Most software and firmware is up to date, but I must be missing something somewhere. These are older devices so I feel like it has something to do with the bluetooth components themselves but my work has a long replacement schedule.

Comment: What type of headset?  For Jabra devices there is a `Prioritize computer audio` setting in Jabra Direct that will cause this behavior.

Comment: @squillman It's a Plantronics Voyager Legend.